# Data structures and algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Okay, I'm trying to do this Programming Project on the book. This is what it says:

> A circular list is a linked list in which the last link points back to the first link.
>   There are many ways to design a circular list. Sometimes there is a pointer to
>   the “start” of the list. However, this makes the list less like a real circle and
>   more like an ordinary list that has its end attached to its beginning. Make a
>   class for a singly linked circular list that has no end and no beginning. The
>   only access to the list is a single reference, current, that can point to any link
>   on the list. This reference can move around the list as needed. (See
>   Programming Project 5.5 for a situation in which such a circular list is ideally
>   suited.) Your list should handle insertion, searching, and deletion. You may
>   find it convenient if these operations take place one link downstream of the
>   link pointed to by current. (Because the upstream link is singly linked, you
>   can’t get at it without going all the way around the circle.) You should also be
>   able to display the list (although you’ll need to break the circle at some arbitrary
>   point to print it on the screen). A step() method that moves current
>   along to the next link might come in handy too.

This is what I have so far, the main method I have cannot be changed.

```java
class circularL
{
    int data;

    circularL next;
    circularL prev;

    public circularL(int d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }

    public int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}

class circularLL
{
    circularL currPt;

    //constructor
    public circularLL()
    {
        currPt = null;
    }

    /******************************************
    * insertLink() function performs *
    * inserting a new link with the data item*
    * to the existing list. *
    *****************************************/
    public void insertLink(int dd)
    {
        circularL theLink = new circularL(dd);

        if(currPt==null)
        {
            theLink.next = theLink;
            theLink.prev = theLink;
        }
        else if(currPt.next==null&&currPt.prev==null&& currPt!=null)
        {
            theLink.next = currPt;
            theLink.prev = currPt;
            currPt.prev = theLink;
            currPt.next = theLink;
        }
        else if(currPt != null)
        {
            theLink.next = currPt.next;
            theLink.prev = currPt;
            currPt.next.prev = theLink;
            currPt.next = theLink;
        }

        currPt = theLink;
    }

    /**************************************************
    * The search() function search for the particular*
    * key by traversing through the linked list. *
    *************************************************/
    public int find(int key)
    {
        circularL tempCurr= currPt;

        if(tempCurr.data == key)
        {
            return key;
        }
        else
        {
            tempCurr = tempCurr.next;
        }

        while(tempCurr.data!=currPt.data)
        {
            if(tempCurr.data==key)
            {
                return key;
            }
            else
            {
                tempCurr = tempCurr.next;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Key not found!");
        return -99;
    }

    /******************************************
    * The delete() function delete the linked*
    * list at the current pointer and return *
    * the value of the data item. *
    *****************************************/
    public int delete()
    {
        circularL tempCurr = currPt;
        currPt.next.prev = currPt.prev;
        currPt.prev.next = currPt.next;
        currPt = tempCurr.prev;
        return tempCurr.data;
    }

    /********************************************
    * The printRing() function prints out the *
    * linked list by traversing the linked list*
    * in either direction. *
    *******************************************/
    public void displayList(boolean direction)
    {
        circularL tempLink = currPt;

        do
        {
            System.out.print(tempLink.getData() +" ");
            tempLink=direction?tempLink.next:tempLink.prev;
        }
        while(tempLink.data!=currPt.data);

        System.out.println("");
    }
}

class CircApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Link f, d;
        circularLL theList = new circularLL();  // make list

        theList.insertLink(10);      // insert items
        theList.insertLink(20);
        theList.insertLink(30);
        theList.insertLink(40);
        theList.insertLink(50);
        theList.insertLink(60);
        theList.insertLink(70);

        theList.displayList();              // display list

        f = theList.find(30);               // find item
        if( f != null)
            System.out.println("Found link with key " + f.iData);
        else
            System.out.println("Can't find link with key 30");
        theList.displayList();              // display list

        System.out.println("Inserting link with key 80");
        theList.insertLink(80);
        theList.displayList();              // display list

        d = theList.delete(60);             // delete item
        if( d != null )
            System.out.println("Deleted link with key " + d.iData);
        else
            System.out.println("Can't delete link with key 60");
        theList.displayList();              // display list

        f = theList.find(99);               // find item
        if( f != null)
            System.out.println("Found link with key " + f.iData);
        else
            System.out.println("Can't find link with key 99" );
        theList.displayList();              // display list

        d = theList.delete(13);             // delete item
        if( d != null )
            System.out.println("Deleted link with key " + d.iData);
        else
            System.out.println("Can't delete link with key 13");
        theList.displayList();              // display list

        System.out.println("Stepping through list");
        for(int j=0; j<theList.getSize(); j++)
        {
            theList.step();
            theList.displayList();
        }

        System.out.println("Will delete and step one by one");
        while(theList.isEmpty() == false)
        {
            theList.delete();
            theList.step();
            theList.displayList();
        }

    }  // end main()
}
```

Comment: Please tidy up the formatting of the code.

Comment: Also do you have any question here?

Comment: I want to do this without giving me error.

Comment: @CssStudent What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Getting errors from the main. If you can grab my code and run it you will see 15 errors. I have to add methods still.

Comment: The problem states that the list should be singly linked, which means that there is no `prev`, only a `next`, in `circularL`. And apparently, `circularL` should be `Link`.

Comment: @CSStudent Why should we "grab [your] code and run it" just to see the errors that you should have shown us to begin with? Seriously, there's no mention whatsoever of any problem or any attempt to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the errors:

1.

```
CircApp.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
    Link f, d;
```

cause: There is no `Link` class that you are trying to make references of.
resolve: Create a `Link` class, or something with similar behavior.

2. On lines 145, 152, 156, 160, 173, 177, 183, 191: you are using method `displayList`, which is `not defined`

   On lines 152, 172: you are using method `delete`, which is `not defined`

   On lines 182, 190: you are using method `step`, which is `not defined`

   On lines 180: you are using method `getSize`, which is `not defined`

   On lines 187: you are using method `isEmpty`, which is `not defined`

Resolve: Define these methods

If you want to run the code before defining these methods, at least create  an empty definition for them or comment these lines.

PS: Don't ever post a code on SO to resolve for compilation errors. This clearly means you don't want to learn.

Comment: "Don't ever post a code on SO to resolve for compilation errors." Then why did you answer and reward the behavior you're trying to prevent?

Comment: Was free at that time. Thought I should help. That's it :)